# Why does my find and replace script always work for everything after the 0 position?

Tags: php, replace, find, str-replace

I'm learning PHP and I've made a simple find and replace script but it seems it only works for characters that come after the 0 position in the string.

here is the script:

```
 <?php

 $offset= 0;

 if( isset ($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['search']) && isset($_POST['replace'])   ){


 $text = $_POST['text'];
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $replace = $_POST['replace'];

  $searchlength = strlen($search);



   if (!empty($text) && !empty($search) && !empty($replace)){

  while ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) {
        echo$strpos;
        $text = substr_replace($text, $replace, $strpos, $searchlength);
        $offset = $strpos+$searchlength;
    }
   echo$text;

    }else{

echo'Please fill in something';
   }


 }




  ?>
 <hr>
 <form action= "index.php" method = "POST">

<textarea name= 'text' rows= '20' cols = '20'></textarea><br>
Search for:<br>
<input type='text' name ='search'><br>
Replace with:<br>
<input type='text' name ='replace'><br>
<input type='submit' value='find and replace'>

  </form>
```

No matter what I do I can never replace the first character or the first word in my string.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset)) {
```

Should be

```
while (FALSE !== ($strpos = strpos($text, $search, $offset))) {
```

For first character, `$strpos` is equal to 0, so `while` loop never starts.